# IDictionary own Implementation IEnumerator

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

Hi I try implemets 2 keys Dictionary and when I compile this code give me message : not all code paths return value in  System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator(). I tried add return statement on many places but it's no effect. Any ideas what is wrong ?

```
public IEnumerator<MultiKeyStruct<PK,SK,V>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var primaryKey in primarykeys)
        {
            foreach (var secondaryKey in primarykeys[primaryKey.Key])
            {
                var returnItem = new MultiKeyStruct<PK,SK,V>(primaryKey.Key, secondaryKey.Key, secondaryKey.Value);
                yield return returnItem;
            }
            yield return default(MultiKeyStruct<PK, SK, V>);
        }
        yield return default(MultiKeyStruct<PK,SK,V>);
    }

    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Comment: On a side note; pretty sure you want to remove the 2nd and 3rd `yield return` statements in the first block; you only want one, the one in the innermost level that actually returns real items.  The other two will put blank items throughout your sequence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the body of your second `GetEnumerator` method should be:

```
return GetEnumerator();
```

The `return` is important.